# remove rows from dataset1 & add those to dataset 2 C#

Tags: c#, dataset

I have 2 datasets, for instances say DataSet1 & DataSet2 with same structure. I need to query DataSet1, get the result, remove those rows from DataSet1 & insert those rows to DataSet2. How to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a condition ready (e.g. **id == 8**), it is easy using linq:

```
var records = DataSet1.Where(d => d.id == 8);
DataSet1.Remove(d => d.id == 8);
foreach (var r in records)
    DataSet2.Add(r);
```